# Trying to dual boot or triple boot three OS's, Windows 7, Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server but ran into errors

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

Tried installing into a new HDD in a Dell mini pc. The optiflex 3020.

I first started by using Disk Management into making the new hard drive into MBR then partitioning the 2TB hard drive into 3 partitions. 1TB then two partions at 500Gb for a total of 3 partitions. Plan was to install windows into the 1TB then 500GB for Ubuntu desktop and the other 500GB for Ubuntu server. But during the installation setup I ended up losing all partitions.

I first installed Windows 7 through a USB stick which went with no problem to the 1TB partition. Chose Legacy boot for the USB install.

I then USB installed (alongside windows) option for Ubuntu Desktop, latest version and also had no problem. I just told it to use the second partition. I didn't have to set up what type of partition or set location of root or anything. Just selected partition and told it to install. Again USB Legacy boot option but this time to the second partion at 500GB. I got the Grub boot loader at the beginning and everything went fine. So everything is working fine at this point. Can switch between WIn7 and Ubuntu desktop.

So I finally then tried to install Ubuntu Server on the third partition of 500GB. On this one I had to setup what partition type EXt4, and setup root location because unless I'm blind I couldn't just tell it to install to third partition then choose "INSTALL". During the install, i got an error message, (sorry didn't take a pic of it) but basically it halted the installation. It allows me to retry the installation so I do that but when I get to the partions menu it shows they are all gone now. Can't install anything. something got corrupted. If I try booting, there is nothing to boot. I just lost both Windows and Ubuntu desktop installs and the time it took to install them >__<

Was this just a fluke or did I do some step wrong for it to kill all the partitions when it was trying to write the Server OS? Any ideas? Could it be that it tried doing grub install again and thats what killed it?

Comment: Ubuntu desktop installer is designed to install alongside Windows. It’s not normal to try to install Ubuntu server alongside something else because a server is intended to run 24/7. It may be possible to do it on a single disk, I have done it with two different disks where Ubuntu server has its own disk. If you only want the server install to experiment with why not install Windows 7 and Ubuntu desktop as you did and install Ubuntu server in a virtual machine? FYI I installed Ubuntu Desktop on my server so I had a convenient alternative to booting off a usb if the need arose.

Comment: so then installing Windows 7 to dual boot with Ubuntu server isn't possible? Or just not easy to do like with dual booting ubuntu desktop and windows?

Comment: If you search on here for “dual boot Ubuntu server” there are plenty of hits the answers to which suggest it should work fine. I’d try it again, perhaps install Windows 7 first then Ubuntu server and finally desktop. You could install the free version of Macrium Reflect in Windows 7 and back up your system at each working step. That might save time if you hit errors again and need to repeat until you get it right.

Comment: I tried WIndows 7 first then Ubuntu server and still got an error. I'll try again maybe on a different system. perhaps it has something to do with the current bios settings on the first system...